# Adapt dynamically outbound-gateway with load-balancing

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I would like to modify (add/remove) the list of outbound-gateway using the loadbalancing of input channel. My code :

```
<int:channel id="mainRequestChannel" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="mainRequestChannel"     message-converters="messageConverters"
                           request-factory="httpRequestFactory" url="http://localhost:8100/batchfactory-slave/receiveGateway"
                           http-method="POST" expected-response-type="JobLaunchingResponse" order="1" reply-channel="finishedResponse" />
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="mainRequestChannel"     message-converters="messageConverters"
                           request-factory="httpRequestFactory" url="http://localhost:8090/batchfactory-slave/receiveGateway"
                           http-method="POST" expected-response-type="JobLaunchingResponse" order="2" reply-channel="finishedResponse" />
```

I modify this and I have now a dynamicRouter :

```
<int:channel id="mainRequestChannel" />
<int:router input-channel="mainRequestChannel" expression="@dynamicChannelResolver.resolve()"/>
```

But there is only 1 subscriber for the mainRequestChannel so the load balancer which is the default behaviour doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [dynamic-ftp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) sample. You would essentially put the outbound gateway in its own context with parameters for the URL etc. However, unlike that example, you would need to make the context a child of the main context (so it will be able to reference the `finishedResponse`channel).

The sample README has a link to some forum discussions where that technique is explained.

Alternatively, you can wire up the necessary classes yourself - you would need a `EventDrivenConsumer` with `mainRequestChannel` and a properly configured `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` in its constructor.

Comment: If you wire up your own components, don't forget to invoke `afterPropertiesSet()` on the message handler, and you will need to `start()` the consumer to make it subscribe to the channel (`stop()` to unsubscribe).

Comment: Thanks Gary, I will read this tomorrow. And Happy New Year !! :)

Comment: Great example. I did all what you said, an extract XML for my outbound-gateway and a child context to reference my output-channel. However, one another question, what is the best pratice to do a loadbalancing with this technique ? If slave1 returns an Exception, how can I call another outbound-gateway ?

Comment: You should really start another question for this, but the default load-balancer is round-robin with failover - the next subscriber is called if the current one fails until one succeeds. You can set the load balancer to `none` to always try the adapters in order rather than load balancing. In 3.0.x you can supply your own load balancer.

Comment: Yes but the channel (your "toFtpChannel") is created in child context and not in the main context, so there is only 1 subscriber by each outbound-gateway and the load balancer doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, yes, but in your case, `mainRequestChannel` should be in the main context; and each http gateway will be subscribed to it, and hence load-balanced.

Comment: I understand, my outbound-gateway take now on input-channel the mainRequestChannel declared in the main context, and my DynamicChannelResolver returns always mainRequestChannel but in creating outbound-gateway if necessary (cache size); and it's works !
Thanks a lot Gary !