# Spring Integration: Direct Channel multiple outgoing endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Please bear with me as I'm still really new to Spring Integration and have just started reading up on it yesterday.

What I'm trying to do is to perform load balancing of sorts for outgoing HTTP calls from my Spring Application. I know I can achieve round-robin and failover with a Direct Channel which is what I'm looking for. But I'm not really sure what to use for configuring outgoing calls.

I read this thread
[Adapt dynamically outbound-gateway with load-balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859415/adapt-dynamically-outbound-gateway-with-load-balancing)

In the OP, I see this *outbound-gateway* tag with a url and method property within. Am i right in assuming that I can use that to configure my outgoing http calls? Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`round-robin` has a simple algorithm: each invocation moves the subscriber `index`  in a circle in the `order` of those subscribers.

So, if you need to invoke an HTTP with the `round-robin` you should just configure something like this:

```
<channel id="balanceChannel"/>

<bridge input-channel="balanceChannel" output-channel="httpChannel"/>

<bridge input-channel="balanceChannel" output-channel="httpChannel"/>

<bridge input-channel="balanceChannel" output-channel="httpChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="httpChannel" url="MY_URL"/>
```

Having that any `send` to the `balanceChannel` ends up in the target the same HTTP call anyway.

Actually it doesn't make sence for the same HTTP, because `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` is thred-safe and can be used concurrently from separete threads.

`round-robin` makes sence in those cases when your target service isn't thred-safe and blocking, so it really would be better just to have several instances for that service.

`failover` makes sence when `load-balancing="none"`. So, the failure of the first subscriber will be treated to the second and so on.